# How to strip part of a string in a pandas dataframe in-place to have the result understood as a timestamp with timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, timestamp

**1. The problem**

I have data in a csv file with timestamps.
Here is an example of the format of these timestamps:

'Fri Aug 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)'

Pandas does not seem to be able to process such a string formatting.
Using the to_datetime function to check if pandas is able to process it, I have the following error:

```
In [3]: pd.to_datetime('Fri Aug 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)')
Out[3]: raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Fri Aug 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)')
```

**2. Logic identified**

But if I remove the blabla, it appears to work:

```
In [4]: pd.to_datetime('Fri Aug 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200')
Out[4]: Timestamp('2017-08-18 00:00:00-0200', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-120)')
```

So the solution to have pandas understanding correctly this column as timestamps with time zones is 1st to strip the blabla:

' (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)'

Then to apply the to_datetime function.

**3. Implementation**

So, I tried to use the following lines of code, and it just is not working.

Dataframe is:

```
,date
0,Fri Aug 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)
1,Sat Aug 19 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)
```

Dataframe is stored as 'GC' 
I tried:

```
for ts in GC[1][:]:
    ts.replace(' (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)')
    ts.to_datetime()
```

I have this output (not very clear to me - I am using spyder, this may be not very helping)

```
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1
```

Please, what would be the correct approach?
I thank you in advance for your help.

Have a good day,

Bests,

Pierrot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with column `date` and `regex=False` for avoid read `()` like regex:

```
s = df['date'].str.replace(' (heure d%u2019été d%u2019Europe centrale)', '', regex=False)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(s)
```

Or you can split values by `\)` with escape `)` because regex special character:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split(' \(').str[0])
```